# Obtener direccion ip local en una App React

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, express

soy estudiante y estoy trabajando en un proyecto.
Mi aplicación debe registrar ventas, cargar lista de productos, listas de clientes y asi.

La tengo divida en dos partes, el backend con nodejs y express corriendo en el puerto 3500 y el frontend con react corriendo en el puerto 3000.

Para hacer las peticiones desde mi frontend (el frontend lo cree usando el create-react-app) hacia el backend utilizo axios de esta manera

```
async fetchData() {
        const { data } = await axios.get(("http://localhost:3500/products/list"))
        this.setState({ listProducts: data })  
    }
```

y funciona perfectamente, ahora la cuestión es que necesito cambiar la dirección de 'localhost' por mi dirección ip local, para que la aplicación funcione desde otro equipo de mi red lan, ya que he probado dejando el "localhost" y no se conecta al backend pero he probado con mi dirección ip, por ejemplo "192.168.1.101" y funciona perfectamente, la cuestión es que la ip puede variar y necesito una manera para obtenerla desde mi frontend.
He probado esto para obtener la ip:

```
var ip
require('dns').lookup(require('os').hostname(), function (err, add, fam) { ip = add; })
module.exports = ip;
```

cuando lo ejecuto funciona, pero cuando pruebo este código dentro de la carpeta 'src' de mi aplicación de react me devuelve 0.0.0.0.
He probado con tambien con os.networkInterfaces, pero como que no funciona dentro del 'src' de react, nose que estoy haciendo mal

Disculpen si hay un problema de redaccion o no queda del todo claro

Comment: intentaste con: `const ip = require('ip');
console.log(ip.address('en0'));` recuerda que el netowork interface esta en: `os.networkInterfaces()` verifica en cada una.... cuando detectes una diferente a 0.0.0.0 te sales del loop

Comment: Al cargar os.networkInterace() me devuelve un objeto vacio

Comment: verifica esto entonces: https://www.edureka.co/community/86164/how-to-get-local-ip-address-in-node-js

Comment: Nunca he trabajado con express, pero creo que en vez de obtener la ip desde tu frontend, deberías hacer [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30712750/895789) o probar alguna de las otras respuestas de esa pregunta.